# Modify appearance of chapter-related entries in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have the following test document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \chapter{AA}
 \chapter{BB}
\end{document}
```

In the table of contents, how can I make chapter entries which look this:

```
Chapter one Introduction
Chapter two AA
Chapter three BB
```

Comment: You should explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have three chapters, Chapter one "Introduction", Chapter two "AA", and Chapter three "BB". As usual, in the table of contents, these chapters appear as follows:
 1 Introduction
 2 AA
 3 BB
 Now, I want these chapters, instead of the common format, appear in the following format:
 Chapet one Introduction
 Chapter two AA
 Chapter three BB

Comment: Do the chapter numbers have to be spelled out as "one", "two" and "three"? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your formatting objective correctly, it has two aspects:

- how to prefix the string "Chapter" to the chapter number in the ToC
- how to typeset the chapter numbers not as arabic numerals ("1", "2", ...) but as words ("One", "Two", ...). I am assuming that you want to use word-style numbers both in the chapter headers themselves and in the table of contents.

I suggest you load the `tocloft` package for the first aspect and the `fmtcount` package for the second.

[image]

You may need to delete the .aux file and re-run LaTeX twice to fully update the appearance of the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{report}

%% Layout of items in ToC
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter } % observe the space after "Chapter"
% measure the required amount of indentation, assign it to "\chapindent" macro
\newlength\chapindent 
\settowidth\chapindent{\textbf{\large Chapter Three}} % store width of string
\setlength\cftchapnumwidth\chapindent

%% Print chapter numbers as "One", "Two", ..., not as arabic numerals
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}} % use "\numberstring" if you want lowercase words

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{AA}
\chapter{BB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have done your commands. But I have get an error as follows:  ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\protect ... 
Is it possible to have a special reason?

Comment: @Farid - Please post the code you're running.

Comment: @Mico- Thank you so much. The problem was resolved and your command are completely right.